# Restricting Salesforce Files to always be in a ContentWorkspace

Tags: files, contentdocument, contentworkspace

Ive tried to figure out how to always require uploaded files to belong to a Library(ContentWorkspace) in Salesforce Files, since the UI/Navigation is not good at all. After some backtracking SOQL queries the Id's are passed on through several objects. We are using a custom object to "hold" the files and leveraging a render LWC for searchability directly in the record.

The two solutions i could think of is that either;

1. Create a validation rule on ContentDocument to require a WorkspaceId, restricting end users from uploading files without being in a workspace.
2. mapping the record types of the custom obj to the different folders in each workspace, hence when file is uploaded directly on record gets sorted into the correct folder in the workspace, this would be a optimal solution but would require a lot of code.

All suggestions are welcomed,

Regards